# How can I select and open links in a VS Code hover widget via keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hover, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to select and open links in VS Code [hover card](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#show-hovers) via keyboard?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Invoke whatever keyboard shortcut binds to the `editor.action.showHover` command twice (by default it should be <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>- you edit the bindings however you want). The first press shows the hover widget, and the second focuses it. Then use <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to do tab navigation. Then press <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>space</kbd> to open the link.

Curiously, [`runCommands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands) is not liking my attempts to put combinations of these keys into one keybinding.